# Syntax sugar for adding singleton dimensions and/or broadcasting

Tags: matlab

I wrote some code that calculates each of the cartesian distances from M N-dimensional points to K centroids, so I have points `(M,N)`, centroids `(K,N)` and I would like an `(M,K)` result. It works, but I find the reshaping and summing along a hardcoded axis really clunky, is there an elegant way to write this?

```
[M Nx] = size(X);
[K Nk] = size(centroids);
assert(Nx == Nk, "Dimensions do not match.")
X_reshape = reshape(X, [M 1 Nx]);
centroids_reshape = reshape(centroids, [1 K Nk]);
distance = sqrt(sum((X_reshape - centroids_reshape).^2, 3));
```

Comment: I think that’s quite nice code. You could use [`pdist2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html), which probably contain code very similar to yours.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thanks, I should have thought to look in the library!

Comment: @CrisLuengo also a good breadcrumb, the octave source for pdist2 has basically the answer to this question (do some algebra to simplify the calculation and use `bsxfun` to broadcast over automatic singleton dimensions efficiently) https://sourceforge.net/p/octave/statistics/ci/default/tree/inst/pdist2.m#l152

Comment: `bsxfun` is no longer needed in MATLAB since R2016a I think. Code is more efficient without it. Before then, you needed to explicitly expand singleton dimensions to match (with `repmat`), which is of course very expensive. Octave has had implicit singleton expansion for a really long time. The author of the code you linked either didn’t know, or implemented that before Octave had that. `bsxfun` is more expansive because it calls a function through a handle for every pair of input slices.

Comment: Ah, this explains it: “Taken from Piotr's Computer Vision Matlab Toolbox” — it was code written for some old version of MATLAB. In any case, I highly recommend comparing execution times of that code with yours. I believe that yours might be more efficient for large data because it doesn’t create intermediate matrices. But you can’t know without trying it out.